# Graph Automorphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, graph-theory, automorphism-group

I'm trying to solve this question:
Show $\pi \in S_n$ is an automorphism over $G = (V, E)$ with $V = \{1,...,n\}$ if there is an edge-set $E'$ such that:
$$E = \bigcup_{i=0}^{\binom{n}{2}} \{ \pi^i(u) \pi^i(v)\ | \ uv \in E' \}$$
But I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how I would go about doing it!

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Just some partial thoughts.

We have usually three steps when proving that something is an Automorphism.

**1. It is endomorphism** So you ask: *if $uv$ edge, is $\pi(u)\pi(v)$ edge?*
In decomposition of $E$, situation $i=1$ gives you this condition for edges in $E'$. Can you then extend it for the whole $E$?

**2. It is surjective** Decomposition gives you that any edge can be written as $\pi^i(u)\pi^i(v)$ for some $i$ and $uv\in E'$.  From this follows that each edge has a pre-image and moreover we know that this pre-image is of form $\pi^{i-1}(u)\pi^{i-1}(v)$

**3. It is injective** Once you have proven this, your proof is complete. (Sorry for not completing the proof)